# Limit vim syntax highlighting to diff

Tags: vim, syntax-highlighting, vim-syntax-highlighting, vimdiff

I am making changes to an existing C code. If I just want to check my changes, I can easily use `vimdiff` for that, with old & modified files.

What I want is to limit some syntax highlighting to just the `diff` part.

Particularly I need to highlight TABS, but only those TABS contained within `DiffAdd` & `DiffChange` sections/regions.

**What I tried**:

```
syntax region TESTRGN start="TESTRGN_START" end="TESTRGN_END"
highlight TESTRGN ctermbg=lightgreen guibg=lightgreen

syntax match LeadingTabsInRegion display contained containedin=TESTRGN /^\( *\t\+\)\+/
highlight LeadingTabsInRegion ctermbg=darkred guibg=darkred
```

Above snippet highlights the leading TABS within `TESTRGN` & tabs in remaining file remain un-highlighted.

However, if I change TESTRGN to DiffAdd in the `syntax match` line, it does not work as I expected.

My understanding is that `DiffAdd` is not a region defined using `syntax region ...` & hence `containedin=DiffAdd` does not work.

So is there any method/work-around for doing what I am trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

First, what's so bad about having the highlighting everywhere? The diff highlighting stands out well and therefore provides visible scope; couldn't you just ignore the highlighting elsewhere?

In Vim, *syntax groups* are defined and then linked to colors and attributes defined in *highlight groups*. The diff stuff uses the second part of that mechanism, **but not the syntax part**. Therefore, you unfortunately cannot refer to the diff regions within `:syntax` commands.

There's only a very ugly workaround for this: You have to determine the line numbers that have diff highlighting (via repeatedly stepping through the changes with the `]c` motion, and/or using `synID()` to check for diff highlighting). With those line numbers, you can then define `:syntax match` commands with the special `\%l` atom that only matches certain lines. Of course, any addition / deletion of lines would invalidate your definitions, which would need to be frequently re-synchronized (triggered by `:autocmd`). That's a lot of effort vs. just ignoring the highlighting elsewhere.

Comment: 'what's so bad about having the highlighting everywhere': Adding new tabs in code is considered as a no-no at many places. Hence adding a disruptive syntax highlighting for such cases - darkred!. For existing tabs, it's actually don't care case. But it's still very much disruptive to ignore. So I thought there could be a better way...

Comment: How does `Diff*` highlights work, if I add a new line above/below such a region? Their line numbers get automatically shifted. So is it line number based, or some rule based?

Comment: Vim has the diffing functionality built in; it's not syntax-based, but triggered internally.

Answer (score 0):

Though you need to reset whenever the line was changed, this is just a tip for one of line number based ideas, you can get a list of all diff highlighted lines with:

```
let dl = filter(range(1, line('$')),
        \'index([hlID("DiffChange"), hlID("DiffText"), hlID("DiffAdd")],
            \diff_hlID(v:val, 1)) != -1')
```

And using this, it might be possible to set your TESTRGN with:

```
exec "syntax match TESTRGN /\\(" . join(map(dl, '"\\%" . v:val . "l"'), "\\|") . "\\).*/"
```